# payara server hosted eclipselink dates are being read from postgres an hour early

Tags: java, postgresql, glassfish, payara

I am attempting to read a Timestamp value from a postgres database.
I have tried various mappings, at the moment I am using the following mapping:

```
@Column(name = "Anlagedatum")
private Timestamp anlagedatum;
```

If I query the database using SQL, I get, **for the first date** `2015-02-27`.

[image]

If I execute the JPA code using a scratch.java on my local machine, I get `2015-02-27`

When the exact same query executes in the context of **MY LOCAL Payara** server, I get an incorrect date. The really wierd part is that my timezone is GMT +2, *not +1*.

The date returned by payara server is `2015-02-26 23:00:00`

[image]

> Why would payara server JPA change the date?
>   How do I change the mapping so that it gets the date stored without manipulation?

Comment: Looks like a summer-time problem?

Comment: @unwichtich thanks - but the question remains - how do I fix it?

Comment: Exactly because of timezone shifts between an app and database, we decided to store dates and times as ISO strings in the DB. ISO format can be easily indexed and sorted and the time won't change when transferring it from the DB. Although it only works if the data and your app are in the same timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This look like a problem with the daylight saving time in your timezone.

First thing to check is which column type you are using in your Postgresql Database. 
You should use: 'timestamp with timezone';

If this is already the case you can try the following:

```
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "Anlagedatum")
private Timestamp anlagedatum;
```

If this doesn't help, I would try it with the 'Date' type in Java:

```
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "Anlagedatum")
private Date anlagedatum;
```